# meaning of "swing open /swing shut"

Tags: expressions

does the expression "to swing the door open /shut" mean that the action was done with force and /or produced a loud noise? or is it just an exact synonym of "to open /close the door"? thanks for the answer. peace

I've searched many different dictionaries and found no answer - hence my question here. how come is it "off-topic"?! isn't it a forum, where users discuss vocab?!

Comment: What has your research shown? I've only heard "swing" in this context used for a gate.

Comment: There could be force, or not.  A door could swing open by itself.  It could produce a noise, or not.

Comment: Please note that *swing*, whether open or shut, is something the door does because of the wind or some other external force, but not human agency.

Comment: @KarlG - actually the swing may be activated by a human being, see examples here: https://www.google.it/search?q=%22he+swung+the+door%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1995,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=w7lLWpjxK5OiUszapegB

Comment: Interesting. "He swung the door shut" sounds really odd to me.

Comment: I've searched many different dictionaries and found no answer - hence my question here. how come is it "off-topic"?! isn't it a forum, where users discuss vocab?!

Comment: No, this ***isn’t*** a forum.  I see that you took the [Tour] 4 days ago; have you already forgotten what it said?

Comment: No, in fact, I've just read it again and it clearly states that questions about the usage of words and phrases are allowed and even welcomed. There are far more simple questions about meaning of word on this site. So why is it a problem, when I ask about a phrase I do not fully understand - and the dicionaries OBVIOUSLY have not cleared much either (otherwise, why would I even bother to waste time on explaining I need some guidance of people who are WILLING to help?).

Comment: "the door of the coupe swung slowly open."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing open/shut does not  involve a strong movement  and a loud noise, unless it is specified, as in the case of  [slam the door shut](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/slam_1):

From McMillan Dictionary:

***[Swing:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/swing_1)***

> 2 [Int/tr] to move in a particular direction with a smooth curving movement, or to make something move in this way.
>
> - swing open/shut: The door swung shut with a loud bang.